# Bootstrap 3 Multiple input group width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I set the width to my input group ? On the first input text I want to set the width to 90% and on the second input text (after the span "P") to 10%.

This is my code http://www.bootply.com/pAcr8C2SGr

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use grid system of bootstrap to set width of input, like:

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <input ...>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <input ...>
</div>
```

Comment: It is impossible in a input-group

Answer (score 0):

[**Try this with out Any CSS Customization**](http://www.bootply.com/lTX2cGQRTn)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Number</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
  <div classs="col-md-3">
<div class="input-group ">
<span class="input-group-addon">P</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon"></span>

  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <input class="btn btn-default" value="Send">
  </span>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Try this with CSS Customization**](http://www.bootply.com/3UwTXgQ1eb)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 custom-col">
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Number</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
  <div classs="col-md-3 custom-col">
<div class="input-group ">
<span class="input-group-addon">P</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon"></span>

  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <input class="btn btn-default" value="Send">
  </span>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Bootstrap do not support multiple add-ons (.input-group-addon or .input-group-btn) on a single side.
>
> Bootstrap do not support multiple form-controls in a single input group.

Comment: There is a problem between the first input and the "P" span I don't want a space

Comment: Umm, thanks for you answer but there is a problem if we resize the browser. I should try another way to do this.